# How do you parametrize the paraboloid to find the flux of $F$ across $S$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the surface integral double integral of $S$ of $F * dS$ for the given vector field $F$ and the oriented surface $S$. In other words, find the flux of $F$ across $S$. For closed surfaces, use the positive (outward) orientation.

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)= y\mathbf{j} - z\mathbf{k}$$
$S$ consists of the paraboloid $y = x^2 + z^2, 0 \leq y \leq 1,$ and the disk $x^2 + z^2 \leq 1, y=1$

I did $x = u\cos t, y = u^2, z =u\sin t$

So to use double integral of $$\vec{F} * dS$$

For parametrization of the paraboloid how do you find $$\vec{F} $$ to be $<0,u^2,-u\sin t>$?

Comment: Do you really need to integrate over the surface, or are you allowed to use the Divergence Theorem?

Comment: Would they mean the same thing? I am not exactly surface what integrating over the surface means. Does that mean finding the area of the surface?

Comment: if the density, or weight, was 1, then it would be area. Instead, you have a nonuniform density over the area, so the surface integral is not necessarily area.

Comment: "Integrate over the surface" is exactly what you are trying to do.  The point is that results such as the Divergence Theorem can often be used to avoid messy calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that $F=(0,y,-z)$, $y=u^2$ and $z=-u\sin(t)$.